# Bootstrap 5 background color is having opacity

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, opacity, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a OR divider, but in bootstrap 5 its not working correctly which is working properly in bootstrap 4. In my project bootstrap 5 is being used. Background color of text is having some opacity.

HTML:

```
<div class="or-line-block pt-2">
    <h6 class="text-center m-0"><span class="or-txt px-2">OR</span></h6>
    <hr class="or-line">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.or-txt{
    background-color: white;
}
.or-line{
    margin-top: -10px;
    border-color: rgba(#333, 0.1);
}
```

In Bootstrap 4:

[image]

In Bootstrap 5:

[image]

[image]

What is the issue. Please help

Comment: This `border-color: rgba(#333, 0.1);` is wrong. Please fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because bootstrap has changed the CSS for `hr`. They've added opacity and some other CSS. Kindly add this to your code

```
hr {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been made this way

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray; text-align: center">
    <span style="font-size: 20px; background-color: white; padding: 0 10px;">
      or<!--Padding is optional-->
    </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might work better to use `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.

CSS

```
   .or-line::before{
      content: "---------"
   }

   .or-line::after{
      content: "---------"
   }
```

Insert anything in the `content` sections and it will appear before and after the work OR.

HTML

```
 <h6 class="or-line">OR</h6>
```